# How do I create a visual report or pie chart showing videos added in a filtered list, using SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, custom-list

The issue is that I can't show new classes, videos, added to the filtered lists, because they are filtered off the main list. So, I can't get any meaningful data.

Any insight about filtering on lists is appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

4 ways to display charts in SharePoint:

1:File Viewer Web Part

2:Quick Chart web part

3:Embed Power BI Report

4:Embed Code Web Part

For more detail information, please refer to this article:https://sharepointmaven.com/4-ways-to-display-charts-in-sharepoint/